# GSON:IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, gson

I'am trying to read .txt file and convert it in targer object, by using GSON

```
2.Operation;
3.Amount;
4.Item_of_expenditure;
5.Balance;
```

This is my code:

```
return () -> {
        ReadFile readFile;
        String fileStringContent = asString(resourceFile);
        readFile = gson.fromJson(fileStringContent, ReadFile.class);
        return readFile;
    };

 private String asString(Resource resource) {
    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), UTF_8)) {
        return FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

But I receive this exception:

```
  IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
```

That's weird considering that the first field in target class has String type:

```
  public class ReadFile {

     private String operation;
     private Double amount;
     private String itemOfExpenditure;
     private Double oldBalance;
  }
```

P.S.:

Comment: *"convert it in JSON"* ... do you mean convert it __to__ JSON? If so, then `gson.fromJson(..)` doesn't convert __to__ JSON, it already expects a JSON.

Comment: of couse! Of course I fixed the error

Comment: But then your issue is also quite clear: you're reading normal text, but you're telling GSON that this is a JSON text. If you want to convert that text to JSON, then you would need to describe how that JSON should look like.